# Summation of distinct column values SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, sum, row

I am new to SQL and I am trying to write a code that looks at every item in a column and returns a column with the sum of each item in that original column. An example is shown below.

```
----------------------------------------------------------
|  Company  |  Payment Type  |  Price      |  PriceType  |
----------------------------------------------------------
|  A        |  Debit         |  100        |  CopyCost   |
----------------------------------------------------------
|  B        |  Cash          |  10         |  FullPrice  |
----------------------------------------------------------
|  C        |  Debit         |  50         |  CopyCost   |
----------------------------------------------------------
|  D        |  Cash          |  20         |  CopyCost   |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

Returns:

```
|  Paymen Type  |  ItemCount  |  TotalPrice  |
------------------------------------------
|  Debit        |  2          |  150         |
------------------------------------------
|  Cash         |  2          |  30          |
------------------------------------------
```

I Wrote a script that performs a similar function but has two issues.

```
SELECT [Payment Type], 
       COUNT(*) ItemCount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN [Payment Type] = 'Debit' THEN [Price] ELSE 0 END) TotalPrice,
       SUM(CASE WHEN [Company Name] = 'Cash' THEN [Price] ELSE 0 END) TotalPrice
  FROM [TableName]
  GROUP BY [Payment Type]
```

The first issue is that it makes a new column with the same name (Shown Below).

```
|  OrderId  |  ItemCount  |  TotalPrice  |  TotalPrice  |
---------------------------------------------------------
|  Debit    |  2          |  150         |  0           |
---------------------------------------------------------
|  Cash     |  2          |  0           |  30          |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

The second issue is that I have to manually put in the name of every unique item in the column but the database is too large for this option to be feasible. 
Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want simple aggregation:

```
select payment_type, count(*) item_count, sum(price) total_price
from mytable
group by payment_type
```

Answer (score 0):

I Found the answer in case anyone runs into this issue:

```
SELECT [Payment Type], 
       COUNT(*) ItemCount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN [Payment Type] = [Payment Type] THEN [Price] ELSE 0 END) TotalPrice
  FROM [TableName]
  GROUP BY [Payment Type]
```